# Error 500 on Ajax Call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I am developing a website where users can write articles. I'm coming across a problem. When a user writes a short article it works fine, but when a user writes or edits a longer article it gives me an Ajax 500 Error in the console. I'm not sure if the problem is happening because I'm working with [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/). Anyways this is the code I'm using to send my article with Ajax:

```
var name        = $(".article_name").val().trim(),
    image       = $("#article_input").val(),
    category_id = $(".txtArticleCategory").val().trim(),
    short_body  = $(".txtShortBodyArticle").val().trim(),
    tags        = $(".txtTagsArticle").val().trim(),
    body        = CKEDITOR.instances['txtArticleBody'].getData();

    if(name !== "" && image !== "" && category_id > 0 && body !== "" && short_body !== "" && tags !== ""){    
      var formData = new FormData($('#insertArticleForm')[0]);
      formData.append("body", body);

      $.ajax({
          xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
              if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);

                //update progress bar width
                $('.progress-bar-custom > span').css('width', percentComplete + "%");    
              }
            }, false);

            return xhr;
          },
          type: "POST",
          url: '/actions/update_article.php',
          data: formData,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          success: function (data) {
              $('.progress-bar-custom').css('display', 'none');
              $('.progress-bar-custom > span').css('width', '0%');

              if(data == 'true'){
                // Empty textboxes
                $(".article_name, .txtArticleCategory").val("");
                CKEDITOR.instances['txtArticleBody'].setData("");

                alert('Article added.');
              }else if (data == "size") {
                alert('Image too big. Max size is 2mb');
              }else if (data == "false") {
                alert('Error, please try again.');
              }
          },
          error: function(){
            alert('Error, please try again.');
          }
      });
    }else{
      alert("Complete a text fields.");
    }
  });
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://sub.domain.net/actions/update_article.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The error only happens when I try adding or editing a large article, anyone know why this is happening or how I can fix it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error is on the PHP side, right? You should add the PHP code and check the error log.

Comment: Error 500 is internal server error. So use debugging tools on server side to determine where it fails

Comment: I'm not sure where the error is. When I write a short article everything works fine, however, when writing a "long" article, about 15 paragraphs is when it fails.

Comment: `/actions/update_article.php` throws the 500 though, right? or where are you seeing the 500?

Comment: Yup, that's the file that throws the error.

Comment: Could it be that I need to maximize my PHP's post_max_size?

Comment: Okay, so it is a PHP error. The JS I'd assume is irrelevant, add PHP and check your error logs. If nothing reported make sure you have logging enabled and are checking the right log.

Comment: Just checked my error log and it's empty.

Comment: A [500 error occurs on any server error](https://www.google.nl/search?q=http+error+500&gws_rd=cr&ei=yNaYWY6hO5DcwQKyyqTABg). However unless received immediately it will be received somewhere along your script. And ***ALL*** I see is [tag:javascript]. So what where you expecting with an un-updated question regarding an internal server error only posting Javscript (which is client only)?? ... ?? ?? ?? Can you enlighten us on that question? Wouldn't it be a profound idea to add the related PHP code to the question??

Comment: I contacted my web hosting provider and they told me it ended up being a ModSec rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted my web hosting provider and they told me it ended up being a ModSec rule. If you're having a similar issue I would recommend contacting them.